# CompoundPredicate NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have for example three NSPredicates.

```
NSPredicate *pred1 = [NSpredicate ...];
NSPredicate *pred2 = [NSpredicate ...];
NSPredicate *pred3 = [NSpredicate ...];
```

And I have from server string how I need combine predicates.

For Example

```
(1 OR 2 OR 3)
(1 OR 3) AND 2
3 OR (1 AND 2)
```

How can I combine my three predicates on the right conditions and given the brackets?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can always create nested `NSCompoundPredicate` like this

```
NSPredicate *orPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[firstPredicate, secondPredicate]];
NSPredicate *andPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[thirdPredicate, fourthPredicate]];
NSPredicate *finalPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[orPredicate, andPredicate]];
```

Comment: Every time I can have different string. And I can have not three, for example ten (1 OR 2 AND (3 OR 4) AND (5 OR 6) AND 7 AND 8 AND 10)

Comment: You can always combine the ones not inside the braces right? like this: (2 AND 7 AND 8 AND 10 AND (3 OR 4) AND (5 or 6) OR 1). Now you can make predicates like this: `NSPredicate *andPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[2,7,8,10]];` and so on...

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to make a "truth table inputs" from your predicates, make a combined predicate based on the string, and evaluate it using truth table data.

In order for the predicate to work on a truth table you need to convert `(1 OR 2) AND 3` to `(SELF[1]==YES OR SELF[2]==YES) AND SELF[3]==YES` format. You can do it with regular expressions:

```
NSString *combine = @"(1 OR 2) AND 3";
NSError *err;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
    regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\d+"
    options:0
    error:&err];
NSString *subst = [regex
    stringByReplacingMatchesInString:combine
    options:0
    range:NSMakeRange(0, combine.length)
    withTemplate:@"SELF[$0]==YES"];
NSLog(@"%@", subst);
```

Next, you can build `NSPredicate`:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:subst];
```

Finally, you need to build your truth table. Evaluate predicates one by one, and place the results into `NSArray`. Place an unused element at index zero, because your substitution strings use one-based indexing.

Now you are ready to use the predicate that you prepared earlier:

```
NSArray *data1 = @[@(NO), @(YES), @(NO), @(YES)];
NSArray *data2 = @[@(NO), @(NO), @(NO), @(YES)];
NSLog(@"%d", [pred evaluateWithObject:data1]); // Prints 1
NSLog(@"%d", [pred evaluateWithObject:data2]); // Prints 0
```

I used fixed values for my truth tables `data1` and `data2`. You would need to evaluate predicates `pred1`..`predN`, and put the results into positions 1..N of the `NSArray`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand after NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:subst];

Comment: NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:subst];
        
        NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        [resultArray addObject:@(NO)];
        
        NSPredicate *currentPred1 = *;
        NSPredicate *currentPred2 = *;
        NSPredicate *currentPred3 =*];
        
        NSArray *arrayPredicates = @[currentPred1, currentPred2, currentPred3];

        for (int i = 0;  i < arrayPredicates; i++) {
            [resultArray addObject:@([pred evaluateWithObject:arrayPredicates[i]])];
        }
        
        [pred evaluateWithObject:resultArray];

Comment: @Alexander That's almost right, except ` [resultArray addObject:@([pred evaluateWithObject:arrayPredicates[i]])]` should be `[resultArray addObject:@([arrayPredicates[i] evaluateWithObject:someObject])]`, where `someObject` is the object that you pass to your `pred1`..`predN` for evaluation. Also the `for` loop needs `i < arrayPredicates.count`, not just `i < arrayPredicates`

Comment: Да, спасибо большое! Попробовал вас найти, хотел с вами связаться, по почте например, но не получилось.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code ex:

```
NSPredicate *p1 = [NSPredicate ];


NSPredicate *p2 = [NSPredicate "];

NSPredicate *p3 = [NSPredicate "];
```

in final predicate

```
    NSPredicate *p = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates: @[p1, p2,p3]];
```

this work like  (p1 AND p2 AND p3)

you can also use orPredicateWithSubpredicates,notPredicateWithSubpredicate with nscompoundpredicate